# Swift - How to pop to root ViewController and perform actions

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am able to pop to my application root view controller like this:

```swift
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

})
```

My goal is to pop to the root view controller, then perform a segue from the root to another view controller. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is your rootViewController a UINavigationController? How are you presenting the controller that you want to pop? and how do you want to present the new controller? push? modal?

Comment: Makes no sense. Dismiss is not pop. If you want to pop, don’t say dismiss. If you say dismiss, you are not popping.

Answer (score 2):

For this the root vc should have a segue then do [ at the below point the root is presenting another vc]

```
let root = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController
root.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
   root.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender:nil)      
})
```

or give id to the destination which is much easier an do

```
root.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {   
   let vc = ///
   root.present/////    
})
```